# Format numbers in input (mask)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that manages the display of my inputs

```js
export const Input = (props) => {
  const {
    name,
    required,
    value,
    label,
    onChange,
    type,
    icon,
  } = props
  const Icon = () => (icon ? <div className="i">{icon}</div> : null)
  return (
    <div className={`field text${icon ? ' icon' : ''}`}>
      <input name={name} value={value || ''} type={type} onChange={onChange} required={required} />
      <Icon />
      <label>{label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to create a mask only on type="number" inputs

example :
the user enters numbers (integer or float) in a form for example : 1000 or 10000

I want to display for the user : 1 000 or 10 000

but the value must always be : 1000 or 10000

At the moment I can convert the number of the user with this :

```js
export const numbersFormatter = (num) => {
  return Number(num.toFixed(0)).toLocaleString().split(/\s/).join(' ') + ',' + Number(num.toString().slice(num.toString().indexOf('.') + 1)).toLocaleString()
}
```

How can I create a mask while keeping my styled component ?

Comment: can you not use a react masking plugin like this: npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask

Comment: There's a library for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj how could I keep the style of my component?

Comment: @AlexandreBuisson Just use NumberFormat instead of your input. It is just an extended input, so it can accept all attributes of input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numberWithSpace = (x) => {
    x = x.toString();
    var pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (pattern.test(x))
        x = x.replace(pattern, "$1 $2");
    return x;
}
console.log(numberWithSpace(1000))
console.log(numberWithSpace(10000))
console.log(numberWithSpace(100000))
console.log(numberWithSpace(1000000))
```

You can do it using this function to format the number.